# How to append tags in a forlop to an array in shopify liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am trying to make an array which already has some tags.. I want to loop through each product in cart and add the tags to the array. The {{tag }} part is working but its not getting assigned to the array..

```
{% assign finalTaglist = "apples, oranges, peaches" | split: ", " %}
        
        {% for item in cart.items %}
          <p>
            {% for tag in item.product.tags %}
                {{tag}}
            
                {% assign finalTaglist = finalTaglist | concat: tag %}
            
            {% endfor%}
          </p>
        {% endfor%}
        
        <p>Final Tag List : {{finalTaglist}}</p>`
```

`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`concat` is used for joining arrays, but your code is trying to add a string to an array, hence why it doesn't work.

Start with an empty string, and use `append` to add on to the string, not forgetting your separator. Once built, use `split` to create the array, then you can `append` to another array if required.

Something along these lines (not tested, just winging it, but you get the idea..)

```
{% assign finalTaglist = 'apples,oranges,peaches' | split: ',' %}

{% assign newTagList = '' %}
{% for item in cart.items %}
    {% for tag in item.product.tags %}
        {% assign newTagList = newTagList | append: ',' | append: tag %}
    {% endfor%}
{% endfor%}

{% assign newTagList = newTagList | remove_first: ',' | split: ',' %}

{% assign joinedTagLists = finalTaglist | concat: newTagList %}
```

Comment: thankyou https://stackoverflow.com/users/10706609/steview

Comment: btw, this seems to work only with literal strings but not with an object such as `ArticleDrop` objects. It will concat the literal string ArticleDrop and not the object with its keys.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone landing here in recent times, a better solution IMHO is to use the sort filter on a non-array to turn it into an array with just that item, then you can pass it to concat.

```
{% assign finalTaglist = "apples,oranges,peaches" | split: "," %}
{% for item in cart.items %}
    <p>
        {% for tag in item.product.tags %}
            {{tag}}
        
            {% assign tag_in_array = tag | sort %}
            {% assign finalTaglist = finalTaglist | concat: tag_in_array %}
        {% endfor%}
    </p>
{% endfor%}
    
<p>Final Tag List : {{finalTaglist | json}}</p>`
```

Source: https://ellodave.dev/blog/article/advanced-liquid-arrays/ (David Warrington)

Comment: I tried your way but facing with error: json not allowed for this object

Comment: Your answer didn't quite work for me because it led to unwanted sorting, but it did inspire me to try simply concatenating the array with a string which works (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

This worked best for me. I created an empty array and then just used `concat` on the strings I wanted to add to the list. It seemed to work just fine with shopify, liquidjs, and the .NET nuget packages I'm using.

```
{% assign statuses = "" | split: "" %}
{% for entity in myCollection %}
    {% if entity.houseIsOpen %}
        {% assign statuses = statuses | concat: "Open" %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if entity.houseIsClosed %}
        {% assign statuses = statuses | concat: "Closed" %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if entity.houseIsExpired %}
        {% assign statuses = statuses | concat: "Expired" %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{{ statuses | uniq | join: ", " | default: "INVALID" }}
```